# Why doesn't the if statement work within this loop? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a while loop that goes through the rows returned from an SQL query. The values of a particular column from that row are stored in an array. The array is then iterated through and each element is compared with the input from the user. If the input matches an array element then a boolean becomes true. I'm trying to do this so that the user can enter a password to access a particular page. However it just doesn't work. I have printed all of the values from the array as well as the input, so I know that there isn't a problem there. But for some reason, the if statement just doesn't compare them. Here is the code:

```
if (isset( $_POST['ok'])) {
  $password = $_POST['pass'];
  $matched = false;
  $pw = array();
  mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx")or die("Error");
  mysql_select_db("details")or die("Error");
  $query="SELECT * FROM members";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    $pw[] = $row["pass"];
  }
  foreach($pw as $p){
    if(strcmp($p, $password) == 0){
      $matched = true;
    }
  }
  if ($matched==true) {
    //Membership page
  } else {
    //Error message
  }
} else {
  ....
```

Comment: try change your loop to foreach($pw as $p){
if($p == $password){
$matched = true;break;
}
}

Comment: And don't forget to **NEVER** store plain passwords, use a **hashing algorithm** on them !

Comment: have you thought of case sensitive issue?

Comment: @ItayMoav break; doesnt make a difference

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV - This is just a basic version for testing, the real one will have a hashing algorithm

Comment: @JohnKenedy - I printed the results from the array as well as the input...so I know that the input is definately in the array...it just doesnt seem to compare and change the boolean

Answer (score 1):

It would be much easier and efficient to change your query to something like this

```
$dbh = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die("Error");
mysql_select_db("details", $dbh ) or die("Error");

$pass = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['pass'], $dbh );
$user = mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST['user'], $dbh );

$sqlQuery = <<< EOQ
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `members`
    WHERE
        `user` COLLATE utf8_bin = '{$user}' COLLATE utf8_bin
        AND
        `password` COLLATE utf8_bin = '{$pass}' COLLATE utf8_bin
EOQ;

$result = mysql_query( $sqlQuery );
if ( $result and ( mysql_num_rows( $result ) === 1 ) {
       echo "success";
       $userDetails = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result );
} else {
       echo "username or password wrong";
}
```

Edit: updated the password and username check to be case sensitive in any case

Edit2: above comments remind not to store passwords plaintext. To change to hashed passwords

```
UPDATE members SET pass = SHA1( pass );
```

Then change your check to

```
... AND pass = SHA1( '{$pass}' )
```

Comment: The reason I am not doing it that way is because I will need to store the column values in an array as they will be used again later on

Comment: if you need all user records later fetch them in addition. especially in this case keep it clean and simple and separate things which do not belong here ( separate authentication and other user data processing )

Comment: I don't understand why people still use the outdated `mysql` module with escaping functions instead of the `mysqli` module or PDO with prepared statements...

Comment: Mysqli indeed is the better adapter. Prepared statements are misused for escaping commonly. Escaping only is a positive side effect of prepared statements but not the original idea.

Answer (score 0):

You need a break after finding a match so that $matched will be equal to true.

```
if ( isset( $_POST['ok'] ) ) {

$password = $_POST['pass'];
$matched = false;
$pw = array();

mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx")or die("Error");
mysql_select_db("details")or die("Error");
$query="SELECT * FROM members";
$result=mysql_query($query);

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
$pw[] = $row["pass"];
}

foreach($pw as $p){
  if(strcmp($p, $password) == 0){
  $matched = true;    // found match so break out and do the membership.
  break;
}
}

    if ($matched==true) {

      //Memebrship page

    } else {

      //Error message
    }

} else {

....
```

Comment: that would execute the script faster but not change anything in the resulting behaviour since he doesn't have an `else { $matched = false }` block in the second (unnecessary) loop

Comment: Unfortunatley this doesnt do anything

Answer (score 0):

Sugestions:

1) Replace the direct mysql function calls with PDO: ( this will not require any escaping, since the PDO will handle everything )

```
$mysql_host = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "xxx";
$mysql_password = "xxx";
$mysql_database = "details";
$dbLink = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_host;dbname=$mysql_database;charset=utf8", $mysql_user, $mysql_password, array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));
$query = db()->prepare("select * from members WHERE pass = ? limit 1");
$query->execute(array($_POST['pass']));
$query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$myMember = $query->fetch();
$query->closeCursor();
```

2) If you want to stick with your code, you could use `$pwd = mysql_real_escape_string($_POSt['pass'])` for the posted password and then select the row containing the escaped received password `$pwd`. Also, do not forget `mysql_free_result($result);`!!!

3) Make a hash of the password therefore you will not need to use mysql_real_escape_string. use `$pwHash = md5($_POST['pass'])` or `$pwHash = sha1($_POST['pass'])` or any combination.

4) Please align your code. It will make it more readable for people answering your questions (offering help) and also for future maintenance (you or someone else; believe me, you`ll forget the code in 2-3 years).

5) Your code should work, I'm not sure why it doesn't. Try adding var_dump for `$pw` and also write something on the screen when the password matches. Maybe you swapped the pages (members with error)

Comment: I added var_dump for $pw, and I also did var_dump for the input text....and from that I could see that the array contains the input string. So I know that there a match, it just seems like it isnt doing the actual comparison and then changing the boolean to true

Comment: what character encoding are you using when connecting to DB? will it be possible that the character encoding to alter the comparison?

Comment: also, try echoing the parameters you are comparing with `strcmp`, inside the `for` loop. see where you get. you could add a echo inside the for where you set the matched to true to convince yourself that the code works well

Answer (score 0):

Why the foreach loop ? You can do it like this:

```
if (isset( $_POST['ok'])) {
  $password = $_POST['pass'];
  $matched = false;
  $pw = array();
  mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx")or die("Error");
  mysql_select_db("details")or die("Error");
  $query="SELECT * FROM members";
  $result=mysql_query($query);
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    $pw[] = $row["pass"];
  }
   $pw_tmp = flip_array($pw);

   if(isset($pw_tmp[$password])){
      //Membership page
   }else{
      //Error message
   }
}else{
  // something else ...
}
```